# XPath: Why does /document-node() match the document node?

Tags: xml, xpath, xpath-2.0, xmlspy, xpath-3.0

An XPath expression of `/` returns the document node.

An XPath expression of `/html` is equivalent to `/child::html` and given an HTML document would return the html element. This is of course evaluated by going to the document node (indicated by the `/`) and then finding the element *child* which is an html tag.

Why then does `/document-node()` actually return the document node?

Given the general XPath expression rules, I would assume `/document-node()` is equivalent to `/child::document-node()`, and `/child::document-node()` should return an empty node sequence (since a document node is never a child of a document node). In fact `/child::document-node()` *does* return an empty node sequence, which leads me to believe that `/document-node()` is not equivalent to `/child::document-node()`. This seems to violate the general XPath expression rules, where an empty axis is an implied child axis<sup>1</sup>.

Is there some special rule such that when you have a step of `document-node()` the axis is assumed to be `self` instead of `child`? I'm using the latest version of Altova XMLSpy (2018 sp1). Alternatively, is this  a bug in XMLSpy? Or is some part of my understanding of general XPath expression rules incorrect?

Note: For anyone who is trying this out, only XPath 2 and XPath 3 support `document-node()`.

<sup>1</sup> Update: As an unrelated FYI, I learned something new from Mads Hansen's answer: in XPath 2 and XPath 3, an empty axis is an implied child axis *unless* there's an attribute test; if there's an attribute test it's actually an implied attribute axis. So while `/html` is implicitly `/child::html`, `/attribute()` is implicitly `/attribute::attribute()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That appears to be a bug in XML Spy.

[3.3.5 Abbreviated Syntax](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-30/#abbrev)

> 2. If the axis name is omitted from an axis step, the default axis is `child`, with two exceptions: if the NodeTest in an axis step contains an AttributeTest or SchemaAttributeTest then the default axis is `attribute`; if the NodeTest in an axis step is a NamespaceNodeTest then a static error is raised [err:XQST0134] .

Verifying with Saxon 9.8.0.8 (HE, PE, EE) and MarkLogic 9.0.3, the XPath `/document-node()` and `/child::document-node()` do not select anything.

These XPaths with different axis names do select the `document-node()`:

```
/self::document-node()
/ancestor-or-self::document-node()
/*/ancestor::document-node()
/*/ancestor-or-self::document-node()
```